# Releasing UIImage after use

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, release, memory-leaks

I want to learn the right way to alloc an uiimage and release it for memory management.
When i use the following code it crashes when deallocating,
   if i dont use [imager release];
program doesnt crash but it shows a leak for imager. Any ideas for solution?

```
UIImage *imager = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:s@"nameofimage" ofType:@"jpg"]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imager];

[imageView release];

[imager release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing memory management is as you have done.

```
UIImage *imager = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameofimage" ofType:@"jpg"]]; 
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imager];
[imager release];
[imageView release];
```

May  be it work if you first release the uiimage than uiimageview

I am not finding any mistake in this code. If the application crashes then check if you are using the same object reference anywhere else after it gets released.